# How to extract integer or float from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got dosage strength values like `20.5 mg`,`20 mg` in string . I want to extract only integer or float value.

Below is what I have tried so far

```
def parseint(self,string):
   return int(''.join([x for x in string if x.isdigit()]))
```

But this is not working in all cases.

ex1)

```
parseint('2 mg')
o/p- 2
```

ex2)

```
parseint('10.2 mg')
o/p - 102
```

Expected output:

```
i/p "20.5 MG" o/p- 20.5
i/p "20.0 MG" o/p - 20.0
i/p "20.0 MG" o/p - 20.0
```

Comment: Hint: `'.'` is not a digit

Comment: use `regex` instead

Comment: 20.5 and 10.2 also aren't integers, your title says floats as well but your question states only integers, which is correct?

Comment: `' . '`  is not a digit. yes that is why it is not coming with integer. how can i have that too.

Comment: `float("20.5 mg".split()[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re


def parseint(string):
    m = re.search(r"(\d*\.?\d*)", string)
    return m.group() if m else None

s1 = "20.5 mg,"
s2 = "20 mg"

print(parseint(s1))
print(parseint(s2))
```

**Output:**

```
20.5
20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parseint(string):
    return float(''.join([x for x in string if x.isdigit() or x == '.']))
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Actually this is working but in one case where values like
"25 MG" . it is giving me output like 25.0, but i think i need 25 only .

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, with `.split(),`float`, and`int`

```
res = [float(i.split()[0]) if '.' in i else int(i.split()[0]) for i in lst]
```

Expanded explanation

```
lst = ['2 mg', '10.2 mg', '20.5 MG']
for i in lst:
    if '.' in i:
        print(float(i.split()[0]))
    else:
        print(int(i.split()[0]))
# 2
# 10.2
# 20.5
```